# Convert an expression to a function

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

If I have a named expression, how can I convert that to a function?  Here's an example:

```
argx: 2*x;
f(x) := argx;
```

I'd like then this to be equivalent to:

```
f(x) := 2*x
```

But I know somehow I have to force "unquoting" or something of `argx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do that.

(1) `define(f(x), argx);`

(2) `f(x) := ''argx;`

Approach (2) only works when you're in the top-level interpreter, since quote-quote `''` (i.e., two single quotes) is only applied when an expression is first parsed. Approach (1) works within functions, while (2) does not, so (1) is a little more general. However, since function definitions are global, there isn't much motivation to define named functions within functions.